# Maximum of each non-empty subarray of an array

Tags: algorithm

How do I find the maximum of each possible subarray (contiguous portions of an array) in time complexity less than O(n^2)?

I have done in O(n^2) time but I am afraid that is too slow. So how can I do it in less than O(n^2) time?

PS. Sorry, I had framed the question different from what I wanted to ask. (This is my first time).

What I had done is kind of like this:

```
for size = 2 to n
    for j = 1 to n - size
        A[j] <- max(A[j], A[j+1])
        increase the frequency of the value v in A[j] 
        in another array every time v occurs as a maximum
```

Comment: can you show us, what you've already tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem in linear time. Start from the beginning and keep a `current_sum` initialized to 0. Iterate over the array and for each element add its value to `current_sum`. If `current_sum` becomes non-positive, make it 0 and continue on with the next element. Otherwise simply continue on with the next element. The maximum sum will be the maximum value that `current_sum` reaches during this process.

It will require a little thinking to prove the correctness of this approach but the basic idea is that appending a portion with positive sum to the subarray will always increase the overall sum.

Comment: I am sorry, but I framed the question wrongly. I did not ask for Maximum Subarray Sum, rather maximum of each non-empty subarray. Will you please help with that? @IvayloStrandjev

Comment: You are looking for n^2 answers - the maximum if each subarray. Thus you can't possibly do that in complexity less than n^2

Comment: Well, I needed to know the number of times each element appears as the maximum of a sub-array, which is doable in time complexity less than n^2. Probably my question was not clear. Anyway I have figured it out, nevertheless, thanks a lot.